# Any way to read the Apple ID from a device connected via USB?

Tags: ios, windows

Let's say I have a non-jailbroken iPhone (4S on iOS 9.3.5 if that matters) and a Windows 7 PC which is trusted. I'm writing a program (well, technically I'm about to) right now and I need it to read the Apple ID from it as soon as I connect it to the PC via cable. I tried several programs like iTools to see whether or not it's possible, and now I think the only way to do it is by reading the ID which was used for purchasing and installing apps. Now I need to know how hard it is and how can I implement it.

Comment: Too lazy to check, but I wouldn't be surprised if that weren't possible. But the question really is: why would you need to do that?

Comment: Long story short, I have to write a program that prevents the unauthorized access to the device by forcing me to prove that I am its legitimate owner by providing the password for the Apple ID tied to the device. Of course, I will never collect and use such data for some shady stuff, nor will I ever publish the finished product itself, I just need to create it so I can finish university, and then I'll just shelve it. Here also comes the language barrier, so some things I just said may sound weird and unfamiliar, but rest assured that I'll never do anything illegal with it.

Comment: So you're adding the additional requirements that you want to check the password for that Apple ID... Note that you can't do much on the device via USB unless the device has "trusted" the computer, which you can't do without unlocking the device, so I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve really. I think we may be facing an XY problem here, it would probably be useful if you took a step back and tried to explain the higher-level view of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No, checking if the password is correct does not require the device, it will try to use the credentials to log into id.apple.com. This part seems easier and I think I can figure it out myself, I only need help with reading the Apple ID from the device which does trust the computer, as I said in the beginning. Again, this thing will never be applied anywhere and it doesn't have to be useful in any meaningful way, I just have to make it so I can get the degree.